# Code mostly works except the second answer problem with quotes in list

Tags: python

```
def car_makes(all_cars: str) -> list:
    lst = all_cars.split(",")
    car_brands = []
    for i in lst:
        brand = i.split(" ")
        car_brands.append(brand[0])
        firms = list(dict.fromkeys(car_brands))
    return firms

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(car_makes("Audi A4,Skoda Super,Skoda Octavia,BMW 530,Seat Leon,Skoda Superb,Skoda Superb,BMW x5"))
    print(car_makes(""))
 
# expected answers
# ['Audi', 'Skoda', 'BMW', 'Seat']
# []
```

Code mostly works except the second answer has to stay empty but I get `['']`. What am I missing here?

Comment: `string.split` on an empty string returns a list containing an empty string.  Perhaps you should do `if not i: continue`.  You would need to initialize `firms = []` before the loop for that to work.  What's the point of doing `list(dict.fromkeys(...))`?  Why not just return `car_brands` when the loop is over?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) documentation:

> Splitting an empty string with a specified separator returns `['']`.

You could check whether the given string is empty and return an empty list in that case:

```py
def car_makes(all_cars: str) -> list:
    if all_cars == "":
        return []
    lst = all_cars.split(",")
    # ...
    return firms
```

Comment: I would use `if not all_cars` to check `None` input as well

Comment: Well, depends on what OP wants to do if `None` is passed. You could return an empty list, return `None`, raise an exception, ...